# How to time a methods execution using chrono in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, execution, c++-chrono

So this is the first time i've tried to do performance measuring and have followed some online resources to test a smaller version of my code before i try it on my coursework. Unfortunately i can't get it to print the time taken to complete the function and i'm not sure if i'm even doing it right.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Timer {
public:
   Timer() {
       startTimept = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   }

   ~Timer() {
       Timer Stop();
   }

   void Stop() {
       auto endTimept = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

       auto start = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(startTimept).time_since_epoch().count();
       auto end = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTimept).time_since_epoch().count();

       auto duration = end - start;
       double ms = duration * 0.001;

       std::cout << duration << "us (" << ms << "ms)";

   }
private:
   std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTimept;
};

int main()
{
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator found, start, nFound;

//ADDS PAIRS OF SENTENCE INTO A MAP
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> sortMap =
   { { "these", "pairs" }, { "the", "correct" }, { "pairs", "makes" }, { "correct", "sentence" }, { "makes", "the" } };
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> swapMap =
   { { "pairs","these" }, {"correct", "the"}, { "makes", "pairs" }, {"sentence", "correct" }, {"the",  "makes"} };

//CREATES CONTAINER TO STORE COMPLETE SENTENCE
   std::list<std::string> resultSeq;

   start = sortMap.begin();

//ADD STARTING WORDS INTO THE LIST
   resultSeq.push_back(start->first);
   resultSeq.push_back(start->second);

//TEMP POINTER TO SOUGHT WORD
   found = sortMap.find(start->second);

//THIS IS THE FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO TEST
   {
       Timer timer();
       for (auto it = sortMap.begin(); it != sortMap.end(); ++it) {
           if (it == found) {
               resultSeq.push_back(it->second);
               found = sortMap.find(it->second);
               it = sortMap.begin();
           }
       }
   }

   for (std::list<std::string>::iterator hard = resultSeq.begin(); hard != resultSeq.end(); ++hard)
   {
       std::cout << (*hard) << std::endl;
   }

   __debugbreak;
}
```

If anyone can spot what i'm doing wrong or offer any links to help with performance measuring that would be very helpful!

Comment: Pop quiz: how exactly does `startTimept` get initialized? Which exact line of code sets its value to the current time, before the performance to be measured actually executes?

Comment: So from what i understand it get initialised in the private section of the ```Timer``` class but i thought ```start``` sets the value to the current time but now i'm looking at it i have a feeling it might not be set at all

Comment: So i've now changed it so that code above sets ```startTimept``` current time inside the ```Timer``` function however it still seems to not work

Comment: When in your program do you want to output the time?

Comment: Did you look at the warning? It looks important. By the way this question isn't really about performance testing, the code is related to that but that's not the aspect which the question is about.

Comment: Oh I see, this is a most vexing parse issue. Funny enough, the example on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) also uses a class called Timer.

Comment: Ok, you fixed one bug. Now, here's your second pop quiz: what does `Timer Stop();` mean in C++. No, it doesn't mean "call the Stop() method of this class".

Comment: @john This trips me up a lot of the time too, but that's not the Most Vexing Parse. It's certainly vexing, but to qualify for Most, you need the temporary inside the initializer. Without it you just get plain-old function declaration.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik By the way that the question is phrase i'm assuming that i have defined another  ```Stop()``` function of class or type Timer? (I'm sorry, i'm still fairly new to coding and need much more practice)

Comment: @user4581301 am i correct to say that this fault is on the line with ```Timer timer()```. I'm a bit confused by the wikipedia explanation

Comment: You should be confused. It's vexing for a reason. The problem you've run into is `Timer timer()` looks exactly like a function declaration, so the compiler doesn't make a variable named `timer` and instead declares a function named `timer` that's never used so the mistake is not caught by the compiler later. Normally you'd use `timer` as a variable later in the code and get a compiler error message saying something like "`Timer`'s not a variable, dude."

Comment: @user4581301 Nah you weren't. Your explanation made a lot more sense to me and i just figured it out before coming back and seeing that you've given the answer haha. Thank you very much for that!

Comment: You could try using a library like "google benchmark" (there are many others). Boost and others also provide classes very similar to your Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`std::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) to measure time differences. The [`std::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) can be anything and does not need to be monotonic. The same goes for [`std::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

> The high_resolution_clock is not implemented consistently across
>   different standard library implementations, **and its use should be
>   avoided**. It is often just an alias for std::chrono::steady_clock or
>   std::chrono::system_clock, but which one it is depends on the library
>   or configuration. When it is a system_clock, it is not monotonic
>   (e.g., the time can go backwards). For example, for gcc's libstdc++ it
>   is system_clock, for MSVC it is steady_clock, and for clang's libc++
>   it depends on configuration.

Further, to encapsulate time measuring, you can take advantage of C++'s RAII mechanism:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Resolution = std::chrono::duration<double,std::micro>>
class Stopwatch {
  typedef std::chrono::steady_clock Clock;
  private:
    std::chrono::time_point<Clock> last;
  public:
    void reset() noexcept {
      last = Clock::now();
    }   
    Stopwatch() noexcept {
      reset();
    }   
    auto operator()() const noexcept {// returns time in Resolution
      return Resolution(Clock::now() - last).count();
    }
    ~Stopwatch() {
      // bad encapulation, you should reconsider this design!
      // e.g. take a std::function as argument to the constructor and call it here
      std::cout << (*this)() << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
  { // the block I want to measure
    Stopwatch sw;
    (void)(1+2+3); // some costly operation
  } // end of measured block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach, if it's just for quick debugging purposes, would be to use `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();`. Since it's pretty wordy, I'd recommend making a wrapper function for it. Anyway, this simply returns the time in milliseconds since 1970 (not sure about that). Then you just stick one before the function and one after it, `cout` the difference and you have the milliseconds that the function took to execute.